# Create Mat from uint16 pointer

Tags: c++, opencv

I am discovering openCV and working on a project in which I have a **C# Plugin** which call a **C++ DLL** to do the treatments. C# deals with Mat but my partner send me a pointer to this matrix from C# to C++. So I am trying to use this pointer to create again a matrix because I don't know how to pass a Mat object between two differente langages through a DLL.

For now, my C++ method is :

```
double CustomData::calculate(LPVOID ptr)
{
    double sum = 0;
    UINT16* src = (UINT16*)ptr;

    for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
            sum += src[y*_width + x];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I want to use `Mat` from **openCV** now to see if the time of the calculation is faster for a mean, and also because I need to perform more operations on this matrix after. So I need to create a `Mat` object from the pointer I get. My best try is the next one :

```
Mat image(_height, _width, CV_16UC1, src);
```

But I get `unsigned char` as data of this matrix. I think I am using correctly the constructor so I think the problem is more in the pointer I pass to the function ?

Comment: `image.data` is always unsigned char, but you can use `reinterpret_cast<unsigned short>(image.data)` if you are using it directly. You may also use the iterators if it is better for you as `cv::Mat::begin<unsigned short>()` the same for `end`. Also, you may access the data directly with `cv::Mat::at<unsigned short>(row,col)` and it will give you the data as unsigned char.

Comment: `Mat image(_height, _wight, CV_16UC1, (uchar*)src);` would work.

Comment: And if I want to convert my int into double to perform operations after, can I do in other way than using `convertTo` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is `unsigned short` (or `ushort`) you can create the matrix as:

```
Mat image(_height, _width, CV_16UC1, (ushort*)src);
```

To get a pointer to the data you shouldn't use `data` (its type is always `uchar*`), but `ptr`:

```
ushort* pointer_to_data_start = image.ptr<ushort>(); // or image.ptr<ushort>(0)
ushort* pointer_to_row_i_start = image.ptr<ushort>(i);
```

Comment: I use this matrix on a loop and so the pointer change at each iteration. So, I create only once the matrix with `image = Mat::zeros(_height, _width, CV_16UC1);` and then use `image.data = (uchar*)src;` and `image.convertTo(image, CV_64FC1);` to be able to perform operation with this matrix. But it seems I can't because the second time I want to use it I have an exception violation of reading.

Comment: This way you just create a header over your data... you shouldn't change the underlying data. You can deep copy the data to overcome this issue: `Mat image = Mat(_height, _width, (ushort*)src).clone();`

Comment: Also, all your requirements (like that data changes, and that you want to use double) should be put into the question asap. Changing the meaning of the question isn't nice since you're wasting the time of people helping you.